# Accessing Apache from remote machine outside network - XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, networking, xampp, portforwarding

I have developed a web application which I want to access from remote machine outside network.

Steps I followed:

1. Configured my router to forward 8080 to 80 on my private IP.
2. Created inbound rule for 8080 and 80 under firewall settings.

After these steps followed, I am not able to access Apache with my public ip address on port 8080.

When I check using [port checker tool](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) it shows that port 8080 is closed on my machine.

Please help

Comment: What OS are you running on your host machine? Does it have a firewall installed which may be blocking this connection? Can you connect to the server from another host inside your local network?

Comment: Windows I am using. I have open port in firewall for 8080 as well as 80

Comment: I am not able to even connect from my own machine using public ip address.

Comment: Can you connect on your local (non-public) IP address? If your inside server IP is 192.168.1.10, does it work if you try from another computer at your home? Are you sure that the server is listening? Run `netstat -a | find 80` and post the results.